# cycles stuck at loading render kernels

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

ever sense I have been using the new LTS version or a newer version of blender its not loading the render kernels or sometimes it will but its just painfully slow even with the default cube scene has anyone else running into this problem and fixed it

im running the optiX on a Nvidia 2070

Comment: That should be a one-time process, but it may happen again on a driver upgrade or a new version of blender.

Comment: I move back and forth between 2.93LTS nd 3.0Alpha, and I must say, despite the described expected behavior, I've had Render Kernels take nearly 10 minutes to load, despite having done so an hour previous (all that changed was I cleared my system cache, I think) - same thing every time - long wait, memory use increases slowly, then quickly, then goes back down a little, then it loads. Sometimes blender goes its "not responding" grey color during this period (sometimes not) but almost always recovers - just after a good amount of time.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Noticed weird hickups too. Nvidia have released new drivers lately so it could be linked to that

Comment: I also noticed it was sometimes extremely slow even after loading the render kernels. Manually unchecking and re-checking viewport denoising checkboxes forced another "loading kernels" loading time, then it worked like before

Comment: Yeah i think this is a problem with nvidia, I recently installed a RTX 4000 in my PC and I also problem with the kernels

Comment: Just upgrade my drivers too, and from around 2 min to load kernels before, to : Too much time for me, i'll just sleep. Is there something i can do about it ?

Comment: I just upgraded to Alpha 3.0.0 for another reason. The kernels took an age to process first time round, but now it loads them instantly - even after restarting Blender. From what I understand that was always how it was supposed to be - it just didn't work for some.